# How to assign a reserved IP address on Fortigate 60C

Tags: router, dhcp

I'm trying to bind mac to ip on FortiWiFi 60C v5.2.6,build711

```
 gw # config system dhcp reserved-address

 command parse error before 'reserved-address' Command fail. Return
 code 1
```

any idea why it not working like it should?

thank you

Comment: [FortiOS Manual](http://help.fortinet.com/fos50hlp/52data/index.htm#FortiOS/fortigate-wireless-52/define-ssid.htm) says `To configure a MAC filter - CLI

Enter
config system dhcp server
show
 
Find the entry where interface is your WiFi interface. Edit that entry and configure the MAC filter. In this example, the MAC address 11:11:11:11:11:11will be excluded. Unlisted MAC addresses will be assigned an IP address automatically.
edit 3
config reserved-address
edit 1
set action block
set mac 11:11:11:11:11:11
end
set mac-acl-default-action assign
end`

Comment: Thnx Zina, you are star.

Comment: For some reason I don't have "Advanced" option in the DHCP Server section. But from CLI it works fine - config system dhcp server | edit 3 | config reserved-address | edit 1 | set mac 11:11:11:11:11:11 | set ip x.x.x.x | end. 
It is really weird that they create different command for fortigate/fortiwifi :(

Comment: I was administering a Fortigate device environment, and the CLI has all options available while the GUI is not able to keep up. As they have multiple devices some have a specific set of commands. The support site was always a great help to me. Are you okay that I put my first comment as an answer?

Comment: Of course, it solved my problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per FortiOS Manual](http://help.fortinet.com/fos50hlp/52data/index.htm#FortiOS/fortigate-wireless-52/define-ssid.htm):

To configure a MAC filter - CLI

Enter

> config system dhcp server
>
> show

Find the entry where interface is your WiFi interface. Edit that entry and configure the MAC filter. In this example, the MAC address 11:11:11:11:11:11 will be excluded. Unlisted MAC addresses will be assigned an IP address automatically.

> edit 3
>
> config reserved-address
>
> edit 1
>
> set ip x.x.x.x
>
> set mac 11:11:11:11:11:11
>
> end

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct.  See CLI output below.

```
# config system dhcp server 

(server) # 
edit      Add/edit a table value.
delete    Delete a table value.
purge     Clear all table values.
rename    Rename a table entry.
get       Get dynamic and system information.
show      Show configuration.
end       End and save last config.
```

Comment: Please don't post an answer to confirm that another answer is correct.  The site's Q&A format reserves answers for solutions to the question, and each answer should contribute another solution.  The way to indicate that an answer was useful is to upvote answers you like.